# adding selected numbers together

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am working on a project that needs to add selected numbers together and show answer. so if I have say 10 textfields with numbers and the user picks three of them I want to show that total.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first question is how does the user "pick" the text fields?

After that it's simply writing a method that uses the same selection criteria to add the values.

Comment: It may be that I can't use text fields for this but maybe pictures with number values?  a user selects different ones and the total is shown in a textbox after a "calculate" button is pressed

Comment: This sounds a lot like a calculator application. You should look into the types of algorithms and techniques for building calculators. For example, I would imagine that a command stack might be a useful idea. Whatever you decide on, one thing you will need to do is establish something to register that a user has clicked on a interface item so that you can act upon it. Whether directly or later on.

Good luck.